# How to get multiple urls from firebase storage as array in firestore document?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have an form (writeUrltoFirestore) which is working except for an array of urls which has to be taken from storage and added to firestore document.

Currently for every file url added in form I have new document at firestore.
So if I select 5 documents and click on "Create" button it will create 5 exactly same documents with only difference their "url" in (writeUrltoFirestore).
As I mentioned it has to create single document in firestore with array of urls for each file stored in storage.

BTW Iam not a programmer - didn't read any book, just always wanted to learn how to make an working app (kinda a dream) so please explain like to a moron if you can and don't get mad if you see something stupid.
Thanks to anyone which is willing to help me.

I need result like this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsiof.jpg)

Here is code below with some explanations.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io' show File;

class Fields extends StatefulWidget {
  const Fields({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FieldsState createState() =>
      _FieldsState();
}

class _FieldsState extends State<Fields> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(child: _Body111()),
    );
  }
}

class _Body111 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  __Body111State createState() => __Body111State();
}

class __Body111State extends State<_Body111> {

  final FirebaseStorage _firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  List<UploadTask> uploadedTasks = [];
  List<File> selectedFiles = [];

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Select files to be uploaded to Storage

  Future selectFileTo() async {
    try {
      FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform
          .pickFiles(allowMultiple: true, type: FileType.any);

      if (result != null) {
        selectedFiles.clear();

        for (var selectedFile in result.files) {
          File file = File(selectedFile.path ?? '');
          selectedFiles.add(file);
        }
      } else {
        print("User has cancelled the selection");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Upload selected files to Storage
  uploadFileToStorage(File file) {
    UploadTask task = _firebaseStorage
        .ref()
        .child("files/${DateTime.now().toString()}")
        .putFile(file);
    return task;
  }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Save files to Storage and get files Urls

  saveImageUrlToFirebase(UploadTask task) {
    task.snapshotEvents.listen((snapShot) {
      if (snapShot.state == TaskState.success) {
        snapShot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((urls) =>
            writeUrltoFirestore(urls));
      }
    });
  }

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Save files Urls to Firestore document

  writeUrltoFirestore(urls) {
    Map<String, dynamic> firestoredocData = {
      "issue type": selectedValue,
      "description": descriptionController.text,
      "location": 'Building A',
      "category": selectedCategory,
      "subcategory": selectedSubcategory,
      "uid": firebaseUser!.uid,
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "url": urls, // HERE I HAVE TO STORE ARRAY OF URLS FROM STORAGE
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    };

    CollectionReference collectionReference =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('issues');
    collectionReference.add(firestoredocData);
  }

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Button that triggers all

  addData() async {
    for (var file in selectedFiles) {
      final UploadTask task = uploadFileToStorage(file);
      saveImageUrlToFirebase(task);

      setState(() {
        uploadedTasks.add(task);
      });
    }

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('created successfully')));

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Other fields from Map above
  List<String> categories = ['111', '222', '333'];
  List<String> generalSubcategory = ['1111111', '2222222', '333333333'];
  List<String> cleaningSubcategory = [
    '1',
    '2',
    '3'
  ];
  List<String> othersSubcategory = ['01', '02', '03'];

  List<String> subcategory = [];
  String? selectedCategory;
  String? selectedSubcategory;

  final TextEditingController descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  String? selectedValue;


  List<String> arrayList = [
    'Individual ',
    'Maintenance '
  ];


  Widget _description() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 35, 0, 0),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: descriptionController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Here you can describe ...',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ),
        maxLines: 8,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) =>
          Stack(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                },
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                          child: _description(),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(13, 0, 25, 0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              boxShadow: const [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  spreadRadius: 2,
                                  blurRadius: 2,
                                  offset:
                                  Offset(5, 5), // changes position of shadow
                                ),
                              ],
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                              borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                            ),
                            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                hint: const Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Categories',
                                      style: TextStyle(),
                                    )),
                                value: selectedCategory,
                                isExpanded: true,
                                items: categories.map((String value) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: value,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 0, 0, 0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        value,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: const TextStyle(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (category) {
                                  if (category == '222') {
                                    subcategory = cleaningSubcategory;
                                  } else if (category == '111') {
                                    subcategory = generalSubcategory;
                                  } else if (category == '333') {
                                    subcategory = othersSubcategory;
                                  } else {
                                    subcategory = [];
                                  }
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedSubcategory = null;
                                    selectedCategory = category;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 25, 0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              boxShadow: const [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  spreadRadius: 2,
                                  blurRadius: 2,
                                  offset:
                                  Offset(5, 5), // changes position of shadow
                                ),
                              ],
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                              borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                            ),
                            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                hint: const Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Subcategories',
                                      style: TextStyle(),
                                    )),
                                value: selectedSubcategory,
                                isExpanded: true,
                                items: subcategory.map((String value) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: value,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                                      child: Text(value),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (subcategory) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedSubcategory = subcategory;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 25, 0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              boxShadow: const [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  spreadRadius: 2,
                                  blurRadius: 2,
                                  offset:
                                  Offset(5, 5), // changes position of shadow
                                ),
                              ],
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                              borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                            ),
                            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                              child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                                dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                ),
                                validator: (value) =>
                                selectedValue == null
                                    ? 'Please select type'
                                    : null,
                                hint: const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Type',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                value: selectedValue,
                                isExpanded: true,
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                items: arrayList.map((String string) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: string,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                                      child: Text(string),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (String? string) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedValue = string;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0)),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: selectFileTo,
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.camera_alt_outlined,
                              size: 30,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            )),
                        const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0)),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 5.0),
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                    const EdgeInsets.all(0)),
                                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                    )),
                                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                    Color>(
                                    Colors.transparent),
                                shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                    Colors.transparent)),
                            onPressed: addData,
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                              ),
                              constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                  minWidth: 120, minHeight: 40),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: const Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Create",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
    );
  }
}
// End of dart file

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Firebase API (separate dart file)

import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class FirebaseApi {
  static UploadTask? uploadFile(String destination, File file) {
    try {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(destination);
      return ref.putFile(file);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  static UploadTask? uploadBytes(String destination, Uint8List data) {
    try {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(destination);
      return ref.putData(data);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call writeUrltoFirestore at last of all upload. Maintain an List at top.

```
List<String> _urls = [];
```

in saveImageUrlToFirebase

```
saveImageUrlToFirebase(UploadTask task) {
task.snapshotEvents.listen((snapShot) {
  if (snapShot.state == TaskState.success) {
    snapShot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) =>
        _urls.add(url.toString()));
  }
});
```

}

In final upload task simply call

```
writeUrltoFirestore(_urls);
```

Comment: When I add writeUrltoFirestore(_urls); at upload task it gives an  error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.

Comment: If I add 
`writeUrltoFirestore(_urls)`
and
`"url": _urls,`
created document appears with empty url

Comment: Have you tried printing your url before actually saving to firestore, just print the map see what's actually going in firestore